# Minecraft server problem

Tags: networking, server, java, minecraft

I have a problem with my server minecraft server. My server is hosted on `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` (Server version, not the desktop) at my home, so my problem is:

I can run my server but I can't join my server (nobody can join), when I try to join I will get `Authentication servers are down. Please try again later, sorry!`, I can join any other server, (so I know this is a problem with the server). When I check in to logs I'll get `Couldn't verify username because servers are unavailable`.

I have tried to change firewall settings (not working for me).

I have tried to set `online-mode` to `false` and I can join the server then but the problem with offline mode is of course only me can join the server.

I have tried to search what the problem is and how to fix and people say the problem is the server cannot connect to internet...

So what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: "People say the problem is the server cannot connect to Internet." Is this true?

Comment: I have asked on stackexchange and the awsner was "Your server can't connect to internet", something like that.

Comment: I mean, can your server connect to Internet or not? Can you ssh to the server and do something like  `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: SSH works, everything works, but I can't join my minecraft server

Answer (score 0):

Your server / host is Not connected to the internet.

Connect your server to the internet.